# Where are all the controller classes instantiated?

Tags: forms, 8

In Drupal 8, if I want to create a form, I have to define a class inside the module folder like this.

```
class MyForm extends FormBase{

   public function getFormId()
   {
     return 'my_form';
   }
   public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
   {

   }
   /* AND ALL OTHER OVERRIDDEN METHODS  */
}
```

Then I need to register a path for it in module.routing.yml.

```
module_name.myform:
  path: '/admin/structure/myform'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\my_formr\Form\MyForm'
    _title: 'My form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer banner configuration'
```

Where is the `MyForm` class instantiated? What calls all the methods we are overriding?

We just define the class and register a path for it; neither we create an object of that class, nor we invoke any of the methods.

So, how does Drupal 8 manage these classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, first, this is not a controller, it's a form class. Controllers are instantiated by the routing component.

Every route must have a controller. _form and some other special cases are processed after routes were collected and the actual controller is added. For forms, that is `\Drupal\Core\Controller\HtmlFormController`.

The actual processing happens in `\Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController::getContentResult()`, which calls `\Drupal\Core\Controller\HtmlFormController::getFormObject()`, which in turn uses `\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolverInterface::getInstanceFromDefinition()` to instantiate the form class.

FormController then hands of the processing of the form to `\Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder`, which uses various other classes in the Form namespace.

Comment: ok so, this how _form & other special classes are instantiated.              now, which routing components/core classes are responsible for instantiating the controller classes (src/controllers).

Comment: @Jasodeep Chatterjee, controllers are a concept of the symfony framework: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html. A map for drupal: https://www.drupal.org/files/d8_render_pipeline.pdf